# How to invoke ".so" file in xcode

Tags: xcode, c99

How to invoke(call) ".so" file in xcode? 
these ".so" files are all writen in standard C.(C99).
Anyone help.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple uses the file extension ".dylib" for dynamic libraries.  They are very similar to ".so" shared-object libraries used in other Unix-like operating systems, and are a cousin to ".dll" dynamic link libraries on Windows.

Most .so libraries are in ELF format (used by Linux and many other POSIX systems) whereas Mac libraries are in Mach-O format.  So, they are most definitely incompatible.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that we should complile the C99 Source code under Mac OS to get the ".dylib" libraries?  ".so" is not suitable on Xcode,I guess.

Comment: @AlexQu - I can't say for sure without more details but probably yes. Maybe it's just the filename that is wrong and the contents are right, but I couldn't tell from the details in your question.  Try typing "file myfile.so" at the Terminal command line and it should report that it's a Mach-O binary if it's just a file naming issue.