# Use native C library (.so) in an iOS App

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, dylib

I have several libraries that I would like to use in an iOS App. They're built for Linux as `.so` files and `.dll` for Windows. Is there a way to use the `.so` files in my Xcode iOS project?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5201241/3844377